# pgsql serial key for each group

Tags: sql, postgresql

The Survey data table (survey_data) looks like

```
groupid| res_q_1| resp_q_2
-------|--------|----------
12     |    1   |61
12     |    3   |20
12     |    3   |39
12     |    3   |24
13     |    1   |53
13     |    2   |60
```

here i tried to create a new temporary table in pgsql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_survey_table;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_survey_table  AS
SELECT 
    (*create temp_serial here*)
    groupid, 
    res_q_1,
    resp_q_2
 FROM survey_data
```

So that the result should be

```
|temp_serial|groupid | res_q_1| resp_q_2
|-----------|--------|--------|---------
|          1| 12     |    1   |61
|          2|  12    |    3   |20
|          3|  12    |    3   |39
|          4|  12    |    3   |24
|          1|  13    |    1   |53
|          2|  13    |    2   |60
```

Any code for (* create temp_serial here *) ?

Comment: consider using `row_number() over()` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SERIAL is a shortcut to `create sequence` and assign it as default value... 
try using `row_number` instead, like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_survey_table;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_survey_table  AS
SELECT 
    row_number() over(partition by groupid),
    groupid, 
    res_q_1,
    resp_q_2
 FROM survey_data
```